# Can anyone solve my Android Fragment issue?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I need to pass Data From Activity to fragment.here below i have attached my code.please help me

This is My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grdView_products_order"
    android:layout_width="258dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.orderfree.order_screen.OrdersListFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have extend Fragment at **com.example.orderfree.order_screen.OrdersListFragment** this class.like

```
public class OrdersListFragment extends Fragment {
              .......
              .......
}
```

And also i am extend Activity on MainActivity class.Like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private GridView productList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     Fragment fr=new OrdersListFragment();
     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

     productList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdView_products_order);

    productList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int                                    position,
                long id) {

        // From Here i need to pass value to That Fragment
       //  Can you tell How to send Value to fragments Dynamically

        }
    });  

   }
```

Comment: i don't have any error in my code.i don't know how to pass data from activity to fragment dynamically.can u help me?

Comment: Yes I can, but I need to see a part of your code.

Comment: i am having lot of works in my project.so i cant post that much of code.please give example how to pass data from activity to fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
package com.example.myfragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

      /**
      * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
      */
      if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         /**
         * Landscape mode of the device
         */
         LM_Fragment ls_fragment = new LM_Fragment();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, ls_fragment);
      }else{
         /**
         * Portrait mode of the device
         */
         PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
      }
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }

}
```

Create two fragment files LM_Fragement.java and PM_Fragment.java under com.example.mycontentprovider package.

Following is the content of LM_Fragement.java file:

```
package com.example.myfragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class LM_Fragment extends Fragment{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      /**
       * Inflate the layout for this fragment
       */
      return inflater.inflate(
      R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
   }
}
```

Following is the content of PM_Fragement.java file:

```
package com.example.myfragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class PM_Fragment extends Fragment{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      /**
       * Inflate the layout for this fragment
       */
      return inflater.inflate(
      R.layout.pm_fragment, container, false);
   }
}
```

Create two layout files lm_fragement.xml and pm_fragment.xml under res/layout directory.

Following is the content of lm_fragement.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#7bae16">

   <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/landscape_message"
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:textSize="20px" />

<!-- More GUI components go here  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the content of pm_fragment.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#666666">

   <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/portrait_message"
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:textSize="20px" />

<!-- More GUI components go here  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Following will be the content of res/layout/activity_main.xml file which includes your fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <fragment
   android:name="com.example.fragments"
   android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <fragment
   android:name="com.example.fragments"
   android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
   android:layout_weight="2"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure you have following content of res/values/strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MyFragments</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="landscape_message">This is Landscape mode fragment
    </string>
    <string name="portrait_message">This is Portrait mode fragment
    </string>

</resources>
```

Comment: It will work only once when the fragments starts.but i need to pass data dynamically on **onItemClickListner()**

Comment: Then try this link    http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-fragments-example-ui-multi-pane.html

Comment: Let me know whether it is working or not?

Comment: Thank you friend for your useFull link

Comment: Its my Pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

use `getActivity()` you can access `protected` and `public` methods.

Your `Activity`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private int data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        data=125;
   }

    public int getMyIntVariable() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Your `Fragment`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)getActivity(); 
        int i = activity.getMyIntVariable();

        return view;
   }
}
```

Comment: It will work only once when the fragments starts.but i need to pass data dynamically on **onItemClickListner()**

Comment: Not true, you call call getActivity() everywhere in your fragment class.

Comment: yeah i can call getActivity() anywhere.but onCreateView will call only once when that class loaded.but i need to get often

Comment: I need to get value from Activity to fragment

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand your problem. getActivity() is available from evrywhere in your Fragment class so...

Comment: you r telling about how to send data from fragment to activity.right? but i need to send data from Activity to fragment

Comment: No... I say that you can GET data FROM Fragment in Activity (Get somethings from B to A is the same that to send somethings from A to B)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to send a string called `clickstring`.Then in the activity:

```
 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name1",clickstring );
fragment = new FragButton1();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

where **FragButton1** is your fragment.

Then in **FragButton1**:

```
  String strtext=getArguments().getString("name1");
        tv=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_times1);
        tv.setText(strtext);
```

I am recieving the data in a string **strtext** and displaying it in a textview.

Comment: It will work only once when the fragments starts.but i need to pass data dynamically on **onItemClickListner()**

Comment: then just put the first part of the code within onItemClickListner()